# How to add a CS project into a VS solution containing a Unity project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am discovering Unity (still totally noob at Unity platform / editor).
I wonder what are the best practises to organize my projects in order to make them available for different Unity projects.

I have C# project MyIaProject that does not know anything about Unity. It just contains  some NON-Unity IA code.
I have created a Unity 2D project MyUnityProject.
I want MyUnityProject to use MyIaProject classes.

It looks that you cannot add a project reference to a unity project as you would do for a non Unity project! The UI just does not allow it.

I just do not want to move all my MyIaProject classes into the MyUnityProject project as I will want to use the same classes in different Unity projects.

Also, I would like to add into the MyIaProject project the needed reference so I can use a vector3d class (= unity 3d position class).
Unity does not seem to be a framework reference that you can add from the "add reference" interface. I did not see any Unity related package in NuGet either.

How am I supposed to solve this riddle?

Comment: [Unity's Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Packages.html). It helps to manage more assets and projects

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the Unity Package Manager. It allows you to reference a package containing code and assets from another location on your disk (and even better for sharing code, from a Git repository). For a piece of code to be usable in the package manager, it would need a `package.json` file describing it. More info [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use git for both the MyIaProject and your Unity project, then you can define MyIaProject as a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in the Unity project Assets folder.

It's all git related (no Unity specifics).

```
cd MyUnitProject/Assets
git submodule add https://mygitrepo/MyIaProject.git MyIaProject
git submodule update --init
```

Then MyIaProject will be located in any MyUnitProject/Assets/MyIAProject. Any change is this folder will be commited and pushed to the MyIAProject only if you use the git commands in the MyUnitProject/Assets/MyIAProject folder (or a git submodule compatible UI tool like SourceTree).

PS: in the unity project root folder you should add a .gitignore like this one https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I would like to add into the MyIaProject project the needed
> reference so I can use a vector3d class (= unity 3d position class).
> Unity does not seem to be a framework reference that you can add from
> the "add reference" interface. I did not see any Unity related package
> in NuGet either.

Regarding this part, here is how to include UnityEngine reference to your .net project:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html